# How to use odnoklassniki api with Meteor

Tags: meteor

i'm trying to use the OK.ru api with meteor to fetch all friends .
but i can't find a way to use the api with meteor , it just keeps on telling me .

> FAPI5 is undefined

i used this exact example [enter link description here](http://apiok.ru/wiki/display/api/HTML+application)
and put this [FAPI5](http://api.odnoklassniki.ru/js/fapi5.js) inside server/lib folder

Answer (score 1):

If your FAPI5 library file is stored in the `server/lib` folder, it should be available on every file within the `server` folder. (and ONLY this folder)

Then again, if you put calls to your FAPI5 library in other subfolders of `server/lib`, say `server/lib/abc`, or if your files are in the same `server/lib` folder but with a name that comes earlier in the alphabet than the fapi file like `abc.js` for example, your library won't be loaded yet. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14987487/1439597).

Also, in your examples, calls are made using `FAPI` method calls (`FAPI.init()` for example), not `FAPI5`. Shouldn't you use `FAPI` instead?