# what do I have to do to include libraries through meteor so I can use typescript?

Tags: meteor, typescript

Using meteor I add jquery and three.js through meteor packages. And a simple javascript file runs to produce the spinning cube example.

Now I change my file.js to file.ts and it Errors: can't find the $jquery or THREE.

Basically the question is what do I have to do to include libraries through meteor so I can use typescript?

Comment: With typescript you do not have an implicit global namespace anymore. You need to either [export](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760462/why-does-typescript-use-the-keyword-export-to-make-classes-and-interfaces-publ) or [import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763684/how-to-require-jquery-via-amd-in-typescript) libs you want to use. [This might be relevant too](http://blog.dataflows.io/technology/2015/04/29/meteor_typescript.html)

Comment: I've looked at this... but it seems the problem is that when I change from js to ts that it tries to run the code before it loads the libraries.

Comment: There must be hundreds of people using these libraries with meteor I think I'm missing something really basic.

Comment: Could this simply be a matter of your [project structure for loading the js files ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109176/ordering-of-the-css-and-js-files-loaded-by-meteor) In short they are loaded (from first to last): Files within a "lib" named folder, the longest (deepest) path, then by alphabetical order. [more here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)

Comment: Using meteor, the libraries are kept in a packages folder; That's ok, it must be at the point of compilation; from TS to JS that it wants to know about the included libraries.... It's not mission critical to my project so  I'm going to seperate my typescript stuff into a file with no dependancies, untill I find the way.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: https://atmospherejs.com/meteortypescript/compiler

'TypeScript is supported on both the client and the server. Files ending with .ts are automatically compiled to JavaScript by this meteor plugin.'

Comment: I've looked at this... but it seems the problem is that when I change from js to ts that it tries to run the code before it loads the libraries.